# WPF : Curly lines are getting drawn differently on different height( y coordinate)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, underline

Issue: I am facing issue in wpf while trying to draw curly lines i.e curls are appearing fine at some points but not on all points for y coordinate.

Observation : Looks like it draws curves correctly only if y coordinate is multiple of width of rect of viewport setting. Like in following code sample it draws line at 126(and other that are multiple of 6) correctly as its a multiple of 6 but not on 140.

Output, First at 126 second at 140 :
[image]"

Expected : It should draw same at all points.

I need curls for all points. May be I am missing something. Any help will be appreciated,  Thanks in advance!

Code Sample :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(GetBrush(), 2), new Point(50, 126), new Point(200, 126)); // Draws fine.
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(GetBrush(), 2), new Point(50, 140), new Point(200, 140));  // Incorrectly draws.
        }

        private DrawingBrush GetBrush()
        {
            Pen path_pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 0.5);
            path_pen.EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;
            path_pen.StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Square;


            Point path_start = new Point(0, 2);
            BezierSegment path_segment = new BezierSegment(new Point(2, 0), new Point(4, 4), new Point(6, 2), true);
            PathFigure path_figure = new PathFigure(path_start, new PathSegment[] { path_segment }, false);
            PathGeometry path_geometry = new PathGeometry(new PathFigure[] { path_figure });



            DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(new GeometryDrawing(null, path_pen, path_geometry));
            brush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
            brush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 6, 4);
            brush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;

            return brush;
        }

    }
}
```